# PHP custom function for array sorting wth usort not working

Tags: php, arrays, usort

I'm working on a magento site php code and trying to sort array using label ASC.
so the values should be sort by label.

I used **usort** function for that

but even i use function output can't see any differences.

Ex-

```
        //$info has the array values 
/*which assigned like this 
 $info['options'][] = array(
                        'id'        => $value['value_index'],
                        'label'     => $value['label'],
                        'price'     => $configurablePrice,
                        'oldPrice'  => $this->_prepareOldPrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
                        'products'  => $productsIndex,
                    );

*/
```

**Sort function is below**

```
 usort($info['options'], function ($a,$b){
                            return strcmp($a['label'],$b['label']);
                        }
                    ); 
var_dump($info);
```

**even i sort or not array shows this output**

```
  var spConfig = new Product.Config(array(10) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "46050"
        ["label"]=>
        string(3) "110"
        ["price"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["oldPrice"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["products"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(5) "95331"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "46071"
        ["label"]=>
        string(3) "120"
        ["price"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["oldPrice"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["products"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(5) "95332"
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "46086"
        ["label"]=>
        string(3) "130"
        ["price"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["oldPrice"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["products"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(5) "95333"
        }
      }
      [3]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "46112"
        ["label"]=>
        string(3) "140"
        ["price"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["oldPrice"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["products"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(5) "95334"
        }
      }          
      [4]=>
      array(5)
      [6]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "46455"
        ["label"]=>
        string(2) "60"
        ["price"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["oldPrice"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["products"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(5) "95326"
        }
      }
      [5]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "46494"
        ["label"]=>
        string(2) "70"
        ["price"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["oldPrice"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["products"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(5) "95327"
        }
      }
      [5]=>
      array(5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "46527"
        ["label"]=>
        string(2) "80"
        ["price"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["oldPrice"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["products"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(5) "95328"
        }
      }  
      
    }
```

I tried few other array keys too but non of them not worked,  Anyone can help me to sort this, Thank You

Comment: Try converting the string numbers to integers

Comment: String to integer casting is not necessary with the spaceship operator.  Answers on this page do not advise best practices.  This page can safely be removed from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting them to integers because a string compare is very different from integer compare. For example, `2` comes lexicographically after than `100`, but that's not what you want.

```
usort ($info['options'], function ($a,$b) {
        $la = intval($a['label']);
        $lb = intval($b['label']);
        if ($la < $lb) return -1;
        if ($la > $lb) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
);
```

---

As of PHP 7, you can directly use the spaceship operator,

```
usort ($info['options'], function ($a,$b) {
        return intval($a['label']) <=> intval($b['label']);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved lots of my time, it seems works fine, I'll run some more tests

Comment: `intval()` calls are not necessary with the spaceship operator because it will treat numeric values as numbers (properly).

Answer (score 0):

change the first parameter of your `usort` implementation from this...

```
usort($info['label'], function ($a,$b){
    return strcmp($a['label'],$b['label']);
}
```

To this...

```
usort($info['options'], function ($a,$b){
    return strcmp($a['label'],$b['label']);
}
```

You were just using the wrong level of the array to sort on.

Comment: sorry i had to edit question little, i tried above solution before but not worked

Comment: This answer is simply and provably incorrect. Proof: https://3v4l.org/ZP7rb Researchers must not follow the advice in this answer.